# Using mass-action law to determine doping densities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, charge-carrier

I would like to understand the solution to part c) given below:

> Find the electron and hole densities in silicon at $300$ K, for each of the following impurity
> densities:
>
> a) Boron atoms at $5 \times 10^{21}\, \mathrm{m}^{-3}$;
>
> b) Boron atoms at $2 \times 10^{22} \,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$ and Gallium atoms at $1.5 \times 10^{22} \,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$;
>
> c) Boron atoms at $10^{23} \,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$ and Arsenic atoms at $10^{23}\,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$.
>
> You may assume that the intrinsic carrier concentration of silicon is $_i = 1.5 \times 10^{16}\,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$.

---

> a) Boron is an acceptor, so the hole density will be $ \approx 5 \times 10^{21}\,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$. The electron density will be $ = {_i}^2/ \approx 4.5 \times 10^{10}\,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$.

> b) Boron and Gallium are both acceptors, so both contribute holes. Thus $ \approx
> 2 \times 10^{22} + 1.5 \times 10^{22} = 3.5 \times 10^{22}\,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$. The electron density will be $ = {_i}^2/ \approx 6.4 \times 10^9\,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$.

> c) Boron atoms are acceptors and Arsenic atoms are donors. Since the dopant densities
> are the same, there are just as many electrons as there are holes. In this case, the
> Fermi level will be in the middle of the band gap and we would expect $ =  = _i =
> 1.5 \times 10^{16}\,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$.

---

It was my interpretation that the mass-action law states that the intrinsic electron and hole density are identical, (basically a statement of charge neutrality); $n_i^2=np$, so this means that before any impurities are introduced there are already $1.5\times 10^{16}$ electrons and $1.5\times 10^{16}$ holes present in silicon.  Since we were told that the intrinsic concentration of silicon is $_i = 1.5 \times 10^{16}\,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$ and we now add $10^{23}$ holes *and* electrons, why is the answer to c) not $n=p=1.5\times 10^{16}\,\mathrm{m}^{-3}+10^{23}\,\mathrm{m}^{-3}\,$?

---

### Edit:

Okay, so it seems I am totally misunderstanding what the mass-action law actually means. For the sake of understanding suppose that ${n_i}^2=16$. My interpretation of this statement is that in the absence of doping there are $n_i=n=p=4$ carriers (per unit volume) - there are intrinsically 4 electrons and 4 holes: this has to be the case as the sample is electrically neutral overall.

Now suppose that the sample is doped with donor density $n=8$, according to mass-action law, $p={n_i}^2/n=16/8=2$. While there were 4 holes to begin with, now there are just 2 holes (per unit volume)? But no charge has been added to the sample, it is still electrically neutral. When the donors ionize, the ions fixed into the lattice have a positive charge $N_D^+$; this has the same magnitude of charge as the 8 electrons added so that $n+N_D^+=0$. But according to mass-action law there are 2 holes leftover, so the sample gains an overall (net) positive charge through doping. Anyone got a problem?

Comment: Because the carriers recombine until $np = n_{i}^{2}$ - the whole meaning of the law of mass action.

Comment: @JonCuster So the $10^{23}$ electrons all recombine with the $10^{23}$ holes?

Comment: Pretty much. Just like mixing a strong acid and strong base - each neutralizes the other.

Comment: @JonCuster Okay, so let me ask you a simple question - Assuming a sample is doped with donor impurity density $\ne$ acceptor impurity density then doping introduces excess (net) charge into sample?

Comment: No - you need to consider both the charge released from the dopant as well as what is left with the dopant atom once a charge (electron or hole) is released.

Comment: @JonCuster I edited my post earlier today (which already accounts for what you just wrote). I have a serious problem understanding this. Is there perhaps some example you give of this (like a hypothetical situation or diagram) that explains things? Many thanks.

Comment: Free carriers are not the only charges in the material, so I'm having a hard time figuring what you are imagining.

Comment: @JonCuster What I'm imagining is the scenario I describe in the edit to my question above. At what point is there a flaw in this argument?

Comment: The semiconductor is fully neutral to begin with. The carrier generation and recombination reactions are all fully charge neutral. There is no excess charge generated in any way. Whether that charge is free to move around is another story.

Comment: @JonCuster Does ${n_i}^2=16$ imply hole number density = electron number density = 4?

Comment: For an intrinsic semiconductor, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doping can never cause your semiconductor to gain a net charge. The total charge is the sum of the free charges (electrons and holes) and fixed charges (ionized donors and acceptors).

In your example you correctly identify that the electron charge is cancelled by ionozed donors. But the same is true for the holes. The holes come from the lattice as well and leave behind negative fixed charges that keeps the overall charge 0.